# Is there a way to unban a user ID (Right click copy ID)

Tags: discord.py

this is what I have so far, any suggestions?

```
@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, member: commands.MemberConverter,):

    await ctx.guild.unban(member)
    await ctx.send(f'{member} had been unbanned')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A member converter is going to be useless, if you wanna unban someone that someone has to be banned and can't be a member on your server. Use the UserConverter instead:

```
@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, user: discord.User):
    await ctx.guild.unban(user)
    await ctx.send(f"{user.mention} has been unbanned!")
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User